# AngularJS: how to simulate a Browser Refresh using routing to fix memory leaks

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, memory-leaks

**Problem:** AngularJS often runs in a SPA environment, where the browser never reloads and memory is never freed.  Consider the case where an application must run for hours and the client instructs that the browser can not be refreshed.  We do have control over the routing.  It seems to me that we should be able to manage memory based upon differentiating routing states.

For that purpose, I have created this Plunker to do a few things:

1. Involve several Angular elements (controllers, directives, services)
2. Involve jQuery
3. Create a memory leak (in Controller.js)
4. Attempt to fix the memory leak by simulating a browser page refresh during routing.

**The Challenge**
Assuming that we do not know where the memory leak is, *the challenge is to fix the memory leak from ngRefresh.js* which features `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart'` and `$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess',`

http://plnkr.co/edit/ihkrBc?p=preview

Comment: If you know what creates the memory leak, then what's the point of your "challenge"?

Comment: The challenge is to assume that we do not know where the memory leak comes from and to attempt to solve it by the normal technique of a "browser refresh."  But, remember this a SPA, so no real refresh occurs, and we are attempting to simulate one. We know the state of memory during Angular's routing and should be able to clean it from there, as a top-down approach to solving it.

Comment: The memory leak is created because the controller messes with DOM outside of its responsibility. As long as you don't 'refresh' the whole page **this** problem can't be solved. Not to mention other ones.

Comment: You're right, I took out the detached DOM to focus on the memory leak instead.

Comment: I don't know what you are referring to, but the situation in your plunker is still the same.